# how to get data from two table in the grid by using stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have create a stored procedure with name getCusnmae1

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCusnmae1]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ALL * FROM dbo.Customers;
    SELECT ALL * FROM dbo.Order1;
END
```

now what i have done so far that create a property class Customer and want to display data on the grid

I wrote the code for this is:

```
conn1.ConnectionString = " server=.\\ms2k5;database=Inventory;Trusted_Connection=true";
            conn1.Open();
            SqlCommand testCMD = new SqlCommand ("getCusnmae1", conn1);
            testCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader myReader = testCMD.ExecuteReader();
            List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
            while (myReader.Read())
            { 
                Customer md = new Customer();
                md.CustName = myReader.;
                md.custname = myReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                md.contact = myReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                list.Add(md);
            }
```

by which I get column value only from the Customers Table
what i Have to do to get data from child table Order1

When I write

```
 md.contact = myReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
```

to acess order table it does not work..

please help
thanks

Comment: It does not work? show the errors!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274) method to handle multiple Results.

```
SqlDataReader myReader = testCMD.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
 { 
  //
 } 
myReader.NextResult();
while (myReader.Read())
 { 
  //
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the data reader is positioned on the first result.
For fetch data from others result use

```
while (myReader .NextResult())
{}
```